# How to uninstall a Google Chrome extension in an uninstaller

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am not asking how to uninstall a Chrome extension manually.

I am distributing my software in a windows msi installer. This MSI also installs a Chrome extension. The method I used is in,

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry

Question: how to uninstall a Chrome extension when a user runs the uninstaller? I tried to follow the instruction above, which asked me to remove HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc\, but it does not work. After removal, the extension still exists.

The part of instruction talking about this is,

To uninstall your extension (for example, if your software is uninstalled), remove your preference file (aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc.json) or the metadata from the registry.

Comment: Do you have control of the Chrome extension's code?

Comment: I do have its source code

Comment: Is this a windows installer issue or a problem with google chrome extensions? Please update the tags if its not related to windows installer or wix

Comment: It is a Google chrome extension problem. Tags updated. Thanks.